# SNAPSHOT or RELEASE in trunk?

Tags: maven, version-control, release

From [Maven Release plugin - Prepare a Release document](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/prepare-release.html), preparing a release goes through the following release phases:

1. Check that there are no uncommitted changes in the sources
2. Check that there are no SNAPSHOT dependencies
3. Change the version in the POMs from x-SNAPSHOT to a new version (you
   will be prompted for the versions to use)
4. Transform the SCM information in the POM to include the final
   destination of the tag
5. Run the project tests against the modified POMs to confirm
   everything is in working order
6. Commit the modified POMs
7. Tag the code in the SCM with a version name (this will be prompted
   for)
8. Bump the version in the POMs to a new value y-SNAPSHOT (these values
   will also be prompted for)
9. Commit the modified POMs

My questions are:

1. Either I perform maven release in trunk (or an integration branch), the head version is always SNAPSHOT?
2. I should decide the next y-SNAPSHOT version (step 8) immediately after the tag? However at the time I release a version, I may not know the next SNAPSHOT version should be MAJOR, MINOR or PATCH change. Can I stop at step 7? But this mean my head version at trunk (or that integration branch) will be RELEASE.
3. Is it bad practice to have head version at trunk as RELEASE?
4. Tester should test the x-SNAPSHOT or the tag version (step 7) or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes
2. Usually, one just increments the version by one. If you want to do patch or minor changes you branch off the released version, you don't touch the trunk.
3. Yes. It's not a release version, it's a work in progress.
4. Depends on your build process and what testing is being performed. Tester should test the version you release into your integration environment, be it snapshot or release version. Some projects deploy continuously, having snapshot versions testable. Some do only release builds whenever they deploy something to an environment.

Comment: For #2, if I branch off from release version (will be from a tag in SVN), I should use `mvn release:branch` or `mvn versions:set` or other way?

Comment: @CKLee again, depends on your use case. You should use mvn release:branch if it fits your usage scenario (see manual entry [here](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/branch.html). In reality there might be cases that you might want to branch off some specific tag in the past and I've myself done it "manually" then.